# Why am i able to run unix commands on my PC?

Tags: unix, cmd, command-prompt

How am i able to execute **UNIX** commands on my PC **Command prompt**? **Note** i **do not** have **cygwin** installed, although i was going to before i discovered this.

[image: Screenshot of command Prompt]

This is a development machine so i have a lot installed on it like ruby, python, git, github, node and so on.
What does this mean? can i use this without cygwin?
Here is a list of programs installed on my PC [program list](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9cxctsqsh4o55gi/ProgramList.txt?dl=0)

Comment: Try `where ls`. It will show you where those tools are installed.

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill, turns out to be BlackBerry Native SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How am I able to execute UNIX commands on my PC Command prompt?

You can use the `where` command in a `cmd` shell to find out the exact location of your Unix commands, for example:

```
where ls
```

This assumes, of course, that `ls` is located somewhere in your current `PATH`.

The location returned will show you in which directory your Unix commands are installed and may be enough for you to determine how they were installed.

---

> The `where` command is roughly equivalent to the Unix `which` command.
>
> By default, the search is done in the current directory and in the
>   `PATH`.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> `WHERE [/r Dir] [/q] [/f] [/t] Pattern ...`
>
> `WHERE [/q] [/f] [/t] [$ENV:Pattern`

Source [where](http://ss64.com/nt/where.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [where](http://ss64.com/nt/where.html) - Locate and display files in a directory tree.

Answer (score 0):

Running Unix commands in windows can be done by having a tool like Cygwin which has those commands.
You can also get many of those commands compiled for windows and then run them using the command with the full path or only the command if the executable is in a path known by adding the paths to the executable files in Windows by :
1) Running in the terminal: `PATH %PATH%;C:\<new_path>` 
2) Creating command aliases like: `doskey np=C:\<new_path>\new_command.exe $*`. `$*` is used to be able to transmit parameters